# Iterate over rows in Excel, Selenium Java

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using an excel sheet :
[Excel snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGlYw.png)
[image: Excel snapshot]

Need to iterate over the rows, one after another after taking the values from `getCelldata(rownum, colnum)` and validating the same from the same row.
But here I need to iterate only the row number.

Code sample:

```
    @Test (priority=1, description = "Login Functionality") 
public void login() {

    driver.get(data.getProperty("base.url"));
    obj_login = new login (driver);
    ExcelBase.setExcelFileSheet("Capacitor_unit");
    obj_login.enter_username(ExcelBase.getCellData(3,1));
    obj_login.enter_password(ExcelBase.getCellData(3,2));
    obj_login.select_login();
}
```

The next one should be `(ExcelBase.getCellData(4,1))` and then `(5,1)` till data ends.

Full class code overview:

```
public class TC01_newDesign extends TestBase{

    login obj_login;
    createNewDesign obj_CreateNewDesign;
    saveDesign obj_SaveDesign;
    capacitorUnit obj_capacitorUnit;
    logout obj_logout;




    @Test (priority=1, description = "Login Functionality") 
    public void login() {

        driver.get(data.getProperty("base.url"));
        obj_login = new login (driver);
        ExcelBase.setExcelFileSheet("Capacitor_unit");
        ..
        obj_login.select_login();

    }

    @Test (priority=2, description = "Create new Design")   
    public void createNewDesign() {

        log.info("Create New Design");
        obj_CreateNewDesign = new createNewDesign (driver);
        ..
    }

    @Test (priority=3, description = "Capacitor Unit Design")   
    public void capacitorUnit() {

        log.info("Capacitor Unit Design");
        obj_capacitorUnit = new capacitorUnit (driver);
        ..

        log.info("Assert actual searched string with expected string from Excel.");
        assertStrings(obj_capacitorUnit.get_unitVoltage().replaceAll("\\s+",""),ExcelBase.getCellData(3,50));
        ..

    }


    @Test (priority=4, description = "Logout app")  
    public void logout() {

        log.info("Logout from CapDes");
        obj_logout = new logout (driver);


    }



}
```

Comment: Just create a variable named rownum and iterate over it using for loop.

Comment: @Naseer Have added full class code overview, what I want is login and logout has to happen only once, once after login 2nd and 3rd Test class has to run in a loop taking data from excel, once data is exhausted, has to end and logout.